# Push Notification Receiving Issues with Parse

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-framework

I am trying to send push notifications via

```
PFPush *push = [PFPush push];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
[push setPushToIOS:YES];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!succeeded)
        WMLog(@"Push sending Error: %@", error);
    else
        WMLog(@"Push Sent.");
}];
```

Somehow on parse.com Push Notifications list is saying that number of subscribers received Push Notifications. But sometime it's not receiving on some devices at the same time some devices are receiving that Notifications and sometimes all devices receiving all Push Notifications. So what could be the reason that why sometimes notifications are not receiving on devices. Looking forward to your response.

**Edit:**
Code is:

```
    PFQuery *requestFromQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kMPFRequestsClassKey];
    [requestFromQuery whereKey:kMPFActivityStatusKey equalTo:kMPFFriendStateConnected];
    [requestFromQuery whereKey:kMPFActivityFriendKey equalTo:objC.objUser];

    PFQuery *fromQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kMPFReflectionsClassKey];
    [fromQuery whereKey:kMPFUsersClassKey matchesKey:kMPFUsersClassKey inQuery:requestFromQuery];

    PFQuery *requestToQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kMPFRequestsClassKey];
    [requestToQuery whereKey:kMPFActivityStatusKey equalTo:kMPFFriendStateConnected];
    [requestToQuery whereKey:kMPFUsersClassKey equalTo:objC.objUser];

    PFQuery *toQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kMPFReflectionsClassKey];
    [toQuery whereKey:kMPFUsersClassKey matchesKey:kMPFActivityFriendKey inQuery:requestToQuery];

    PFQuery *reflectionsQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fromQuery, toQuery, nil]];
    [reflectionsQuery orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];
    [reflectionsQuery setLimit:1000];

    PFQuery *pushQueryFriends = [PFInstallation query];
    [pushQueryFriends whereKey:kMPFInstallationUserKey matchesKey:kMPFUsersClassKey inQuery:reflectionsQuery];

    PFQuery *pushQueryOwners = [PFInstallation query];
    [pushQueryOwners whereKey:kMPFInstallationUserKey equalTo:objC.objUserReflectionOwner];

    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pushQueryFriends, pushQueryOwners, nil]];
    [pushQuery whereKey:kMPFInstallationNotificationEnableKey equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [pushQuery whereKey:kMPFInstallationUserKey notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Comment: Are you targeting all devices which are type IOS and have an entry in Installation Class ?

Comment: No, It's for only iPhone and iPod.

Comment: And Installation class has entry in it

Comment: Can you paste your pushQuery here for better understanding of your issue ?

Comment: see updated statement.